Lexicographic order and partial order
Let ∑ = {a; b} and suppose that ∑ has the partial
order relation R = {(a; a); (a; b); (b; b)}.
Let ≥ be the corresponding lexicographic order on ∑*
is this statement true
aba ≥ abb.
my work :
I just looked at the alphabetical order and determined what is greater than the other then aba < abb because a < b in the alphabetical order.
but according to the relation :
a ≥ a
a ≥ b
b ≥ b
So aba > abb because a > b in the relation.
which one is true and why because i am so confused

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

You are confusing 'lexicographic' order with (the usual) alphabetical order.
The partial order relation tells you how to order 'letters' in your system. Lexicographic order is then the extension of this relation to 'words' in your system, based on the given partial order relation.
